# gdb "Couldn't find method ..." (Method from a library)

Tags: c++, gdb

I compiled my code only with `-g` flag. I have this exact expression in my code:

`auto b = some_func(row[0].as<MyType>());`

But when I want to inspect part of the expression:

```
(gdb) print row[0].as<MyType>()
Couldn't find method pqxx::field::as<MyType>
```

I get this error. Even though I run it in the debugger when in the same block of code the whole expression is.

(the library in which the method resides is a C++ PostgreSQL libpqxx.so)
(gdb 8.3)

---

That's not the only thing that doesn't work. When I do:

```
(gdb) print my_unordered_map.find(MyType(1))
A syntax error in expression, near `1))'.
```

Or:

```
(gdb) print my_unordered_map.find(my_lambda(row[0]))
Invalid data type for function to be called.
```

(also for just `my_lambda(row[0])`) Even though exactly this was compiled.